# Training neural network on massive dataset using tensorflow is slow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, regression

I am trying to train a DNNRegressor using tensorflow estimator api with a massive dataset of about 1.2Tb consisting of 50 000 GZIP compressed CSV files.
I know using TFRecord files is much faster but converting 50 000 files will take ages.

Each row of data consists of 1035 float features and 2 float labels I am trying to predict (yes it's huge).
The map function create the input and also does the normalization using a scaler file containing the Max&Min of each feature.

I am using parralel_interleave for my input pipeline since the content of each files contains similar data with slight variation. To create shuffled batches, I read 5 lines from 10 different files to create a somewhat shuffle batch of size 50.

```
def tf_input_function():
  files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files('D:/Data/training/*gz')
  dataset = files.apply(
      tf.data.experimental.parallel_interleave(
          lambda filename: (tf.data.TextLineDataset(filename, compression_type="GZIP")).map(parse_csv,
                                                                                          num_parallel_calls=8).batch(
            batch_size).prefetch(1),
        cycle_length=10,
        sloppy=True,
        buffer_output_elements=10,
        prefetch_input_elements=1))
  iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

  features, labels = iterator.get_next()

  return features, labels



def parse_csv(line):
  fields = tf.decode_csv(line, FIELD_DEFAULTS)
  labels = fields[-2:]
  del fields[-2:]

  # Pack the result into a dictionary
  feats = dict(zip(COLUMNS, fields))
  # Separate the label from the features

  return scaleFeatures(feats), labels

def scaleFeatures(features):
  index = 0
  for x in features:     
          min_x = minmax[index][0]
          max_x = minmax[index][1]
          if max_x != min_x:
              features[x] = (features[x] - min_x) / (max_x - min_x)
          index += 1
  return features

def run_model():
  feature_columns = [
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column(name)
    for name in COLUMNS]

  est = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(
    config=tf.estimator.RunConfig(
        save_checkpoints_steps=100000,
        keep_checkpoint_max=5000,
    ),
    feature_columns=feature_columns,
    hidden_units=[1500],
    label_dimension=2,
    optimizer=lambda: tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0001),
    dropout=0.5,
    activation_fn=tf.nn.leaky_relu,
    model_dir="D:/Stock Data/n1"
)
  train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=lambda: tf_input_function('train'),
                                    max_steps=TRAIN_STEPS)

  eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=lambda: tf_input_function('validation'), steps=EVAL_STEPS)

  tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(est, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

The issue is that the pipeline I am using to feed my network is super SLOW.
For 100 steps (each step has batch size of 50) it takes ~6seconds to train.
Here's the output from the DNNRegressor training :

```
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 40.882965, step = 6365506 (13.298 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 19.33
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 25.407375, step = 6365606 (5.189 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 19.8323
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 80.53043, step = 6365706 (5.032 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 19.943
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 542.24744, step = 6365806 (5.011 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 19.9351
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 21.753256, step = 6365906 (5.046 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 23.0136
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 50.146282, step = 6366006 (4.321 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 19.9311
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 38.326336, step = 6366106 (5.012 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 14.869
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 56.946716, step = 6366206 (6.724 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 18.1742
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 33.119816, step = 6366306 (5.500 sec)
```

The files are stored on an HDD capable of at least 50MB/s read speed but when monitoring during training it reads the files at a combined speed of 2MB/s ... is it because it has to read multiple files thus non sequential reads ? (overhead of moving the head of the HDD etc ...)
I tried using an SSD (SATA 3) and it's even slower ...

[image]
Also training with parrallel_interleave consumes 100% of my CPU.

So my most important question is if there is a way to dramatically speed up training ?

Training this way will take me 30 days to complete 1 single epoch ...

Note: Using GPU is slightly slower than using CPU so I believe the problem is with with how my pipeline is set up

Comment: You should convert input to TF format, or at least unzip those files. I suspect most of cpu time is used for unzipping.

Comment: Thank you, that was my next step. A read speed of 2MB/s is just way too slow

Comment: What GPU are you using? What is GPU utilization? Sometimes increasing batch size can help increase GPU load and thus decrease epoch time.
Have you tried profiling? What IDE do you use? You can find the exact function in the tensorflow backend which is bottlenecking your code.

Comment: @Sharky Thank for the reply. I am using a GTX 980. Utilization is around 9% with batch size 50, if I increase the batch size to 100 it becomes extremely slow and GPU utilization drops to 3% or less. I am guessing the input data pipeline is bottlnecking everything. 
I am using Intellij IDEA, will try profiling again and comment back with what I get.
Thanks !!!

Comment: Besides unzipping and pre-scaling beforehand, you can try using CsvDataset - https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#consuming_csv_data.

Comment: @user1776576 If possible for you (if you have multiple `CPUs and/or GPUs`), you can `Distribute the Data Processing` among `multiple Machines/GPUs` using `Data Parallelism`, which can be achieved using `Tensorflow Distribution Strategy`. Thanks!